# stack text on top of each other make text bolder (arabic)

Tags: html, css

I have this problem that there is a border around the text when stacking that same word over itself.
you see I'm trying to color diacritical marks in Arabic like "كتب" vs "كُتُب"
there is no direct way to do that.
so I write the text twice one with the diacritical marks and the other without, then stack them together just like in container1:

```css
body,
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px
}

div p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.container1 p.colored {
  color: red;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container1 p.base {
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* container2 */

.container2 p.base {
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* container3 */

.container3 p.colored {
  color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container3 p.base {
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* container4 */

.container4 p.colored {
  color: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container4 p.base {
  color: #000;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">

<head>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container1">
    <p class="colored">
      كُتُب
    </p>
    <p class="base">
      كتب
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <p class="base">
      كُتُب
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container3">
    <p class="colored">
      كُتُب
    </p>
    <p class="base">
      كُتُب
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="container4">
    <p class="colored">
      كُتُب
    </p>
    <p class="base">
      كُتُب
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

but if you can see there is a border to the text in container1 with the color red.
if you can't see it try changing the color from the devtool with the color Picker.
how can I prevent this effect? thanks
note that i can't change the font weight of the colored paragraph.

Comment: Remove the rule `color: red;` from the `colored` class?

Comment: I cannot see the `border` around the text...can you please clarify?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I guess OP is talking about some 'border'?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i need it to color the diacritical marks.

Comment: you could try to give `text-shadow` or `drop-shadow()` on your `.base` element. But that's an ugly hack.

Comment: What OS/browser/font combination is being used to recreate the issue? Like Vivek, I see no border.

Comment: @VivekK. please try to use the dev tool color picker and change the container3 p or container4 p color it will be easy to spot.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think OP did not explained it well. I think he's speaking about the red pixels that is exactly below the black one. The browser cannot hide the red pixels that are present on the characters edge. Make the font smaller and you'll see the  red artifacts.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I understand the explanation, but I am not able to reproduce in my environment. So I'm asking about environmental details. Is that odd?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I tried something like that but it won't work for me unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way is to use `::before` pseudoelement

[image]

1. inside the `content: ""`
2. putting the vowels one by one (without their letter)
3. the vowel need to be in UNICODE

> now 100% it will work because there isn't the letter but only the vowel

### TLDR, here is the table:

| arab | name | Unicode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| َ | fatha | `\064E` |
| ُ | damma | `\064F` |
| ِ | kasra | `\0650` |
| ّ | shadda | `\0651` |
| ْ | sukun | `\0652` |

### code example:

```css
* {
  font-size: 20vmin;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
}

.text::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  right: 1ch;
}

.fatha::before {
  content: "\064E";
}

.damma::before {
  content: "\064F";
}

.kasra::before {
  content: "\0650";
}

.shadda::before {
  content: "\0651";
}

.sukun::before {
  content: "\0652";
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
  <p class="text fatha">كَ</p>
  <p class="text damma">كُ</p>
  <p class="text kasra">كِ</p>
  <p class="text shadda">كّ</p>
  <p class="text sukun">كْ</p>
</div>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
  <p class="word"><span class="text fatha">كَ</span>تب</p>
  <p class="word"><span class="text damma">كُ</span>تب</p>
  <p class="word"><span class="text kasra">كِ</span>تب</p>
</div>

<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around">
  <p class="word"><span class="text shadda">كّ</span>تب</p>
  <p class="word"><span class="text sukun">كْ</span>تب</p>
</div>
```

> attention: the position isn't precise when compared to real letter with vowels
>
> but if you don't compare to real one, it should work fine. (like the first image on the top)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me try playing with the color picker and make the text identical in both in the p and the ::before so that you and focus in the border problem.

Comment: @abdosayed updated with another solution see now

Comment: That's a really cool solution but it doesn't work, unfortunately, see I edited your snippet the marks from ::before don't match the real ones added in the text and the problem gets bigger if you use it in a word, not a letter.*I find a solution and it's to use a font design tool. my solution is not CSS based and is a little ugly.
in my example the one with two texts one with the marks to color and the other without, I used a new font I created using a font editor for the marks text. the new font is the same as the other font but with the characters colored transparent.

Comment: note that my solution has many problems, for example, colored characters can't change color or font weight by CSS.(don't know if there is a way to change that) so if you use my solution don't color the marks so that you can do that by CSS.

Comment: @abdosayed yeah, I know your feeling, is very difficult to do this with HTML, and have many bugs (it works fine in one letter but not more) maybe we can use a script JavaScript that split every letter and for every letter create a div and add the before class correct) and is very hard because I tried for example the "fatha" with N is different position, then the K. and we need to solve it to every letter and is a pain. sorry I tried to do my best (I have english keyboard so I can't type arabic, I copy from internet so it also harder to me to create script that work for every letter) sorry :/

Comment: don't worry at all. thanks very much for your help I really appreciate it.